# keyerror while checking for values that exists in a dictionary

Tags: python, json, keyerror

I keep getting a `keyerror` in python.
I am using `requests` and getting back a `json` with 3 values. I am trying to extract only the elevation.

```
r = requests.get(api_url +str(lat) +"," +str(longi) )
resp = json.loads(r.text)
print(resp)
print(resp['elevation'])
```

this is the response for `resp`:

```
{'results': [{'latitude': 30.654543, 'longitude': 35.235351, 'elevation': -80}]}
```

this is the error:

```
KeyError: 'elevation'
```

Comment: Did you mean: `print(resp['results'][0]['elevation'])`?

Comment: Just want to explain the above comment. `resp` is, to say so, a dictionary with included list with included dictionary. `resp["results"]` returns you the list; `resp["results"][0]` returns you the first element of this list and it is the dictionary, and inside this dictionary there is the key `elevation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is responding with a list (holding one dictionary) as the value. So you would access with resp["results"][0]["elevation"] because "elevation" is not in results, it is in results[0] (zero index of the list results) and you can tell this by the "[{   }]" denoting a list holding a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If you format the JSON (`resp`) a bit to be easier to undestand, you get something like this:

```json
{
   "results":[
      {
         "latitude":30.654543,
         "longitude":35.235351,
         "elevation":-80
      }
   ]
}
```

(I used [this tool](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#))

You can see that the "toplevel" is an *object* (loaded as a python `dict`) with a single key: `"results"`, containing an *array* of *objects* (loaded as a python `list` of `dict`s).

- `resp['results']` would be `[{'latitude': 30.654543, 'longitude': 35.235351, 'elevation': -80}]` - the said array
- `resp['results'][0]` would be the 1st element of that array: `{'latitude': 30.654543, 'longitude': 35.235351, 'elevation': -80}`
- `resp['results'][0]['elevation']` would be `-80`

I suggest using a `for` loop to iterate trough the elements of `resp['results']` to process all resoults.

Comment: Be sure to always accept the answer if it solved your problem so others can find it too (and that also gives points to the answerer)

Answer (score 0):

The response is a dictionary whose 'results' key holds a list of dictionaries. In your case this list holds only one entry. So, you must traverse the entire path to get the value you want.
Try:
resp['results'][0]['elevation']

Comment: it's a list not an array

Comment: it is a list indeed

Comment: thx for the help, I now understand the error and got it to work